# API for receiving JSON via POST receives a different type than sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, body-parser

I'm writing an api that gets a JSON in NODE.JS. The method of sending the data is POST.

To ease the management of requests I'm using lib Express and BodyParser to interpret the body of POST requests.

I'm grouping information into a javascript object like this:

```
const data = {
    "plan": "312409959F9FDDE444959F9C950201D7",
    "sender": {
        "name": $("[name=pname]").val(),
        "email": $("[name=pemail]").val(),
        "hash": credentials.hash,
        "phone": {
            "areaCode": $("[name=pphone]").val().substring(0, 2),
            "number": $("[name=pphone]").val().substring(2, 11)
        },
        "address": {
            "street": $("[name=paddress]").val(),
            "number": $("[name=pnumber]").val(),
            "complement": $("[name=pcomplement]").val(),
            "district": $("[name=pbairro]").val(),
            "city": $("[name=pcity]").val(),
            "state": $("[name=puf]").val(),
            "country": "BRA",
            "postalCode": $("[name=pcep]").val()
        },
        "documents": [{
            "type": "CPF",
            "value": $("[name=pcpf]").val()
        }]
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "type": "CREDITCARD",
        "creditCard": {
            "token": credentials.token,
            "holder": {
                "name": $("[name=pownername]").val(),
                "birthDate": $("[name=pbirthday]").val().split('-').reverse().join('/'),
                "documents": [{
                    "type": "CPF",
                    "value": $("[name=pcpf2]").val()
                }],
                "phone": {
                    "areaCode": $("[name=pphone2]").val().substring(0, 2),
                    "number": $("[name=pphone2]").val().substring(2, 11)
                }
            },
        }
    }

}
```

The request is sent as follows:

```
$.post('/adherence', data, function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
})
```

And the receipt on my backend is like this:

```
app.post('/adherence', (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send("OK");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send(e);
    }
});
```

But what I get in req.body is this:

```
{ plan: '312409959F9FDDE444959F9C950201D7',
 'sender[name]': 'FRancisco',
  'sender[email]': 'falisson.sv@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br',
  'sender[hash]': 'ceedf0fd2ffd35f4054104d305088e19e8ca9333bbf70be10bd2ea6f94af226a',
  'sender[phone][areaCode]': '63',
  'sender[phone][number]': '991047876',
  'sender[address][street]': '1105 sul qi 3 al 3 lt 1',
  'sender[address][number]': '1',
  'sender[address][complement]': '',
  'sender[address][district]': 'centro',
  'sender[address][city]': 'palmas',
  'sender[address][state]': 'TO',
  'sender[address][country]': 'BRA',
  'sender[address][postalCode]': 'CEP',
  'sender[documents][0][type]': 'CPF',
  'sender[documents][0][value]': 'CPF',
  'paymentMethod[type]': 'CREDITCARD',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][token]': 'b2f303ba63964404b6c466323deb9078',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][name]': 'LUCINEIA',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][birthDate]': '11/01/1990',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][documents][0][type]': 'CPF',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][documents][0][value]': 'CPF',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][phone][areaCode]': '63',
  'paymentMethod[creditCard][holder][phone][number]': '991047876' }
```

In my opinion, everything is normal, and it was for me to be receiving the JSON in the format sent. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: which library are you using to post the data? It appears that the post method is using some unconventional serialization of the data.

Comment: @elemetrics jQuery. But i'm just tried send with Ajax even so the error persists.

Comment: perhaps try to convert the data to a JSON string via JSON.stringify:

$.post('/adherence', JSON.stringify(data), function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
})

Comment: if JSON.stringify doesn't work, try dropping the quotes around the object keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending your request like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/adherence',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    })
});
```